# UWP: Use NTLM credentials to call PUT Webservice

Tags: c#, uwp, authorization, httpclient, windows-iot-core-10

I'm developing an UWP-App. Therefore I have created a PUT-Webservice with windows authentication.

**First I've tried to call it with this code:**

```
JPasswordChangeData jPasswordChangeData = new JPasswordChangeData()
{
    OldPassword = oldpassword,
    NewPassword = newpassword
};

var credential = new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>", "<domain>");

string apiServerSecurePath = "https://MyServername:6501/";
var myCache = new CredentialCache();

// Add the target Uri to the CredentialCache with credential object
myCache.Add(new Uri(apiServerSecurePath), "NTLM", executingCredentials);

// Create an HttpClientHandler to add some settings
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
handler.Credentials = myCache;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient
    .PutAsync(apiServerSecurePath + "api/ActiveDirectory/ChangePassword/" + username,
    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jPasswordChangeData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

But then I get the error:

```
The value 'System.Net.CredentialCache' is not supported for property 'Credentials'.
```

**Next I've tried to use "Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient":**

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
filter.ServerCredential = new PasswordCredential("<Domain>", "<username>", "<password>");
filter.AllowUI = false;

JPasswordChangeData jPasswordChangeData = new JPasswordChangeData()
{
    OldPassword = oldpassword,
    NewPassword = newpassword
};

Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient windowsHttpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);

//HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpResponseMessage = await windowsHttpClient.PutAsync(
new Uri("http://MyDomain:6001/api/ActiveDirectory/ChangePassword/" + txtblk_samaccountname.Text.Trim()),
new HttpStringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jPasswordChangeData), Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json"));
```

I've also set the needed Funcions in the Package.appxmanifest.

I'm sorry, that I only have the screenshot in german. Here's the translation:

- Internet (Client & Server)
- Internet (Client)
- Private Networks (Client & Server)
- Enterprise Authentication

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

But then I get this Response from the webservice:
[image: Servererror]

Translated it means:

401 - Unauthorized: Access denied due to invalid credentials.

The given credentials do not authorize you to view this directory or page.

Does someone have an idea what's my failure?

Tank you in forward!

Best Regards

Matthias

Comment: If you simulate these operations directly in fiddler, were you successful?

Answer (score 0):

Now I know a little bit more, but I don't have the solution...

I haven't said that the UWP is developed for a raspberry with Windows 10 IOT Core.

When I try to send the Credentials from a PC in the domain it works.

When I try the same code on the raspberry it doesn't work.

I think the reason is that the reaspberry is not in the domain. But I can't joined Windows 10 IOT Core to a domain. Only a Windows 10 IOT Enterprise can be joined to a domain. But Windows 10 IOT Enterprise can't be installed on a raspberry.

So I think I have to add basic authentication to my webservice. If someone has an idea how I can use the credentials of an active directory user I'll be very thankfull!

Comment: Yes, for `Windows Authentication`, the client and service should be in the same domain. For authenticating with AD without in the same domain, you could try Basic Authentication. The service will validate the User Credential by AD without checking whether it is in the same domian. What you need is to proivde the right user credential.